# Why can't I add / change permissions for mysql

Tags: mysql

Every time I try and add a permission I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

This happens using `mysql` in the terminal and through `PhpMyAdmin`

The user doing the change is root with all permissions and GRANT option. Does not matter what I set the permissions to either, all, with grant, without grant, just select. they all just have this error.

Any ideas why?

#### Extra info:

recently upgraded from 5.0.1 -> 5.6

I have restarted mysql

I have tried flushing privileges

```
# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.19, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

mysql> select current_user();
+----------------+
| current_user() |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select user();
+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>  SELECT host,user,password,Grant_priv,Super_priv FROM mysql.user;
+---------------------------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------+------------+
| host                      | user             | password                                  | Grant_priv | Super_priv |
+---------------------------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------+------------+
| localhost                 | root             | *hash                                     | Y          | Y          |
| localhost                 | debian-sys-maint | *hash                                     | Y          | Y          |
...trim...
+---------------------------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------+------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out yum did not update the db,

```
2014-07-14 14:49:27 2135 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_history' has the wrong structure
2014-07-14 14:49:27 2135 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_history_long' has the wrong structure
2014-07-14 14:49:27 2135 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2014-07-14 14:49:27 2135 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_summary_by_account_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2014-07-14 14:49:27 2135 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_summary_by_user_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2014-07-14 14:49:27 2135 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_summary_by_host_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2014-07-14 14:49:27 2135 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_summary_global_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
```

running `mysql_update -u root -p<pw>` sorts it out

Answer (score 1):

Try `mysql_fix_privilege_tables` - upgrade MySQL system tables.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar today on Gentoo. There `mysql_upgrade` fixed things for me.

Looking at the details of a gdb session, `mysqld` crashed when the function `replace_user_table`, called from `mysql_grant`, tried to access the `MYSQL_USER_FIELD_PLUGIN` a.k.a. `plugin` column of the `mysql.user` table, which was still absent on my system.

I consider it rather bad style that the server will crash if the system table schema is outdated, but apparently that's the way it is written.